# diff -u -s, line cound (+, -) not giving correct value

Tags: shell, cmd

I am using diff -u -s file1 file2 and counting + and - for Added and deleted lines in files for File comparison automation. (Modified lines will also count as one + and one -). These counts match with Araxis tool compare statistics (Total Added+Deleted of script=Changed+deleted+new of Araxis) for most of the files. But script total and Araxis total does not match for few files.

P.S. - I am using cygwin to run script on windows. I tried dos2unix, tail -c 4 etc in hope of removing BOM characters. But out of these culprit files some of them does not have BOM, and still count does not match. Following are few sample culprit files.
(1)SIACPO_ActivacionDesactivacionBlacklist.aspx.vb - Script gives 57 total count, while araxis 55
(2)SIACPO_Suspension_Servicio.aspx - Script gives 2509 total count, while araxis 2473
(3)repCuadreProceso.aspx - Script gives 1165 total count, while araxis 1163
(4)detaPago.aspx.vb - This is strange file. There is no change at all, except BOM character on 1st line. Script gives 0, 0 count, then why at all this in modified list of files??

Now how can I attach these 4 culprint files (Dev as well as Prod version) for your troubleshooting?

Comment: How are you comparing the directories and how are you counting the changed files ?

Comment: (1) I am using find . -type f for all files and redirecting in a txt file. Then I use diff -u -s prod_files.txt dev_files.txt to find out new and deleted files count (removing first 2 lines and then greping +  and -) 
(2) And for line count in a MODIFIED filed, I am using diff -u -s tempdev.txt tempprod.txt and counting +, - (after removing first 2 lines). Many other egrep also used to handle various situation in modified files. Not sure how to share whole script and culprit files here.

Comment: You need to show the code if you need our help. What is the difference with Araxis statistics ? Have you tried `diff -q dev_dir prod_dir` to count the changed files ?

Comment: Issue is with the changed "lines", instead of changed files. There are 2 level of comparison I need to do. One is folder level (files count) and other is file level (line count). I am stuck with line count issue. Please let me know how can I share my script as well as culprit files here or let me know if I can email those one to one. Thanks for your response.

Comment: Diff tell you how many lines are added and removed. How you define changed lines ?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: To add code here, paste it into your question, select it, and click the code/block button. Do not beg for help. Keep your question focussed on one thing, and avoid requests that are too broad. Don't ask multiple questions per question. Don't ask to email projects to people - the point of this site is to help people in public, so that other people find that helpful.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion @halfer. I am new to this forum so missed these points. But I will keep these in mind in future..

Comment: @matzeri - I told to client that modified lines will be treated as "One added" and "One deleted" lines in script. So there is no modified lines count, instead only Added (+) and Deleted (-) line count. These counts are in-line with Araxis statistics too, except few files for which I am looking expert suggestion here.

Comment: On StackOverflow, we hope to read a [mcve] version of a problem. There is probably 1 line of code that is causing your problem, but we have to try to understand a "large" body of code to see if we can help. This is probably why you haven't received much help. You can help yourself (possibly solving your problem yourself), by creating 1. a simple script that people can run on the cmd-line that will create the smallest file that demonstrates the problem and 2. then a simple script that runs on that "bad" file and demonstrates the error you are getting. ....

Comment: It would be best if we can just copy/paste your commands into our terminal window, and get the same results as you do. Then we can figure out where the problem is (and you might figure it out yourself). At least reduce your script to focus on the "files line count problem", we don't need the "directory counts" code to think about your problem. AND Does  your code really need to be stored in files that use `BOM`s? Your problem might go away completely if you can eliminate those. Good luck.

Comment: Please edit your Q to include the output of `uname -srv ; set | grep LANG` . Also, as you only tagged your Q with `[shell]` and you have studiously avoiding using `$(...cmd...)` form of command-substitution, you might want to also include the first line of your script? Are you really using `#!/bin/sh`? If not, then add `[bash]`, `[ksh]`, etc as appropriate to your Q. This will change dramatically the number of people that are looking at your Q. Good luck ;-)

Comment: I have edit the question so that fellow members might get idea of issue. I am still trying to find the way to attach two version of files for troubleshooting.